# RFC822 Date format in Golang

Tags: go, rfc822

Why Golang time format (RFC-822 in this case) is different from the one described in the RFC?

In `time` package RFC822 const value is defined as:

```
RFC822 = "02 Jan 06 15:04 MST"

11 Nov 09 00:00 CET
```

But regarding to [RFC-822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc822.html) or [w3.org Validator](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/error/InvalidRFC2822Date.html) date format should be rather as RFC1123:

```
RFC1123     = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 MST"

Wed, 11 Nov 2009 00:00:00 CET
```

or even better:

```
RFC1123Z    = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700"

Wed, 11 Nov 2009 00:00:00 +0100
```

Because the Central European Time Zone (CET) is not correct in this RFC.

Why such a difference?
I'm writing an RSS server and it took me a while to figure out why I'm getting badly formatted results.

Comment: The format used for RFC822 perfectly matches what is defined in RFC 822 section 5.1. Day and seconds are clearly marked as optional there.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after here - if you are asking, "why did the developers of go do it this way," that's probably a question better asked at https://github.com/golang/go.

Having said that...a couple of things:
(1) Why are you getting worked up over RFC822?  Use a format you like better, since it's clear you prefer 1123.
(2)RFC 822 makes the seconds optional - there is nothing wrong with omitting it.  `hh:mm` is perfectly valid under 822.  Ditto for the day (this is why it's listed as `[ day "," ]`  - the brackets mean "optional")

Comment: It's not that I don't like it (I ended up using the longer version in my code), but I approached the matter with a completely opposite path, i.e. RSS -> Validator -> RFC. Absolutely everywhere where there are requirements for RSS, the format described as required is "RFC-822", but my code using "time.RFC822" returned different results than expected. "Problem" solved, but I managed to get annoyed why standard != standard. And while I can agree that the day of the week and the seconds are optional, the timezone "MST" (CET in my case) is not correct.

Comment: Yes, I read (later) that RFC822 should be applied to local time, but I still don't really see the logic why it was done that way...
Maybe at least there will be a trace if someone in the future has similar problems.

Comment: Hear, hear. Insanity looms for those tinkering with Go's `time` package. I'm doing something similar (generating RSS feeds) and baffled at the way these so-called 'standards' have been implemented (or should I say... interpreted?). Thanks for pointing it out!